# WPF Binding MaxDropDownHeight property to the grid row height

Tags: wpf, combobox, grid

I have a comboBox and I want to bind dynamically the MaxDropDownHeight property to the second row height.

Here the xaml:

```
  <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="6*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <ComboBox MaxDropDownHeight="">

    </ComboBox>
</Grid>
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binding to second row of `Grid` you can achieve in two ways:

First: by `RelativeSource` bining:

```
<ComboBox DropDownOpened="ComboBox_DropDownOpened" 
          MaxDropDownHeight="{Binding Path=RowDefinitions[1].ActualHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Grid}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">       
</ComboBox>
```

Second: by `ElementName` binding (in this case you must set in grid `Name="RootLayout"`):

```
<ComboBox DropDownOpened="ComboBox_DropDownOpened" 
          MaxDropDownHeight="{Binding ElementName=RootLayout, Path=RowDefinitions[1].ActualHeight, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">            
</ComboBox>
```

In `DropDownOpened` event handler you should update value of  `MaxDropDownHeight` by using `BindingExpression` class.

```
private void ComboBox_DropDownOpened(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ComboBox cb = sender as ComboBox;
    BindingExpression be = cb.GetBindingExpression(ComboBox.MaxDropDownHeightProperty);
    be.UpdateTarget();
}
```